# Environment for different kinds of lists

Tags: lists, environments

I would like to have one environment so as to display numbered list or bullet/plus list. Here is a pseudo code.

```
\begin{myList}[1)]
    \item Text...

    \item Text...
    \begin{myList}[bullet]
        \item Text...
        \item Text...
    \end{myList}

    \item Text...
    \begin{myList}[plus]
        \item Text...
        \item Text...
    \end{myList}
\end{myList}
```

Here is what should be the output (* symbolizes one bullet).

```
1) Text...
2) Text...
    * Text...
    * Text...
3) Text...
    + Text...
    + Text...
```

How can I acheive this ? Is there a robust solution ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [`enumitem` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/enumitem) provides an optional `label` key-value parameter that can do this for either `enumerate` or `itemize`. Since your outer-most list has numeric values, use `enumerate`, while the inner ones can use `itemize` (although `enumerate` would produce equivalent results). Here's a working minimal example showing the structure:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}% http://ctan.org/pkg/enumitem
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}[label=\arabic*)]
    \item Text...
    \item Text...
    \begin{itemize}[label=\textbullet]
        \item Text...
        \item Text...
    \end{itemize}
    \item Text...
    \begin{itemize}[label=+]
        \item Text...
        \item Text...
    \end{itemize}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}​
```

Comment: Thanks but is there a way to use only one single environment instead of the both ones ?

Comment: You can *just* use `enumerate` if you want to. But you can't use `itemize` for all three.

Comment: Sorry, I've just saw it in your answer...